# How to concatenate with getter and setter?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function to filter different bank transactions, and trying to optimize with 2 parameters but **my concatenation with the getter does not work.**

Is it a way to write this good.
My entity Transactions has these properties: `type` ("debit" or "credit"), category (restaurant, food, etc etc), date, amount

I would like to filter with only one function: so I could filter category = restaurant

```
public function filter($sortOf, $search) {

        $transactions = $this->getTransactions();
        $transactionsFiltred =[];
        foreach ($transactions as $transaction){

            if ("$transaction->get . $sortOf()" === $search){

                $transactionsFiltred [] = $transaction;
            }
            dd($transactionsFiltred);
            return $transactionsFiltred;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `"$transaction->get . $sortOf()"` <-- remove the double quotes. And you might need to add parenthesis `$transaction->(get . $sortOf)()`

Comment: Well, rather something like `$transaction->{"get" . $sortOf}()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks
It works with

```
 $getter = 'get' . ucfirst($sortOf) . '()';
            if ($transaction->{"get" . $sortOf}() === $search){

}
```